# Can we develop streams in c++ using AWS sdk c++

Tags: amazon-web-services, c++11, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I created a table with streams enabled, how can i get the stream records whenever update/insertion is happened? What are the steps involved? Or it is not possible in C++?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it using the sdk for C++.

Here there is an example
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-a-thread-pool-with-the-aws-sdk-for-c/

The AWS blog has many examples more https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/category/cpp/

Check these links below (look at aws-cpp-sdk-kinesis) for more info:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-sdk-for-c-now-ready-for-production-use/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-the-aws-sdk-for-c/